# Rails:Running on prod mode in dev box: Asset not found 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm running a rails app in production mode in my local desktop. It however throws a 404 for application-xxxxxx(Checksum value).js and the css. However they both exist in the public/assets directory after I did a rake precompile. Do I have to manually add them to the asset load path? If so, why does it not load this automatically? Is'nt it implicit to have public/assets to the assets path?

Answer (score 2):

In production environment it is assumed that external web server (like nginx) will serve static file from `public/asset/` directory. So if you run production environment on dev box you need either to run web server which servers those static files, or configure production environment to serve static files by rails server:

```
# in config/environments/production.rb

config.serve_static_assets = true # change from false
```